# Re-loading Swf file from sdcard as3 Android

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, flash, external

I am working on an android app where I wish to download swf files from an external server, save them to sdcard and load them later in the app. Downloading works fine and the swf is saved in the application directory. Here is my code that loads the swf from the sdcard :

```
var myloader:Loader = new Loader();
var myhomeButton:btnHome = new btnHome();

addChild(myloader);

var swfFilePath:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("Android/data/myswffile.swf"); 
var inFileStream:FileStream = new FileStream(); 
inFileStream.open(swfFilePath, FileMode.READ); 
var swfBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
inFileStream.readBytes(swfBytes);
inFileStream.close();

var loaderContext:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, ApplicationDomain.currentDomain);
loaderContext.allowCodeImport = true;
myloader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, mycompleteHandler);
myloader.loadBytes(swfBytes, loaderContext);

function mycompleteHandler(evt:Event):void
{
    myloader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, mycompleteHandler);
    addChild(myhomeButton);
    myhomeButton.height = _height * 0.08;
    myhomeButton.width = myhomeButton.height;
    myhomeButton.x = 10;
    myhomeButton.y = 10;
    myhomeButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, myexitfftn);
}

function myexitftn(evt:Event):void
{
    myloader.unloadAndStop(true);
    removeChild(myhomeButton);
    gotoAndStop(1, "SomeOtherFrame");
}
```

the problem is when I click the exit button the swf unloads but when I reload it, it starts from the second frame of the loaded swf, the third time from the third frame and so on... Where am I going wrong or what is an alternative solution, please guide.

Answer (score 0):

Try, `addChild(myloader)` in `Complete` handler and `removeChild` and `null` while exiting, so that loaded `swf` is completely removed from the memory like so:

```
function mycompleteHandler(evt:Event):void
{
    myloader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, mycompleteHandler);

    addChild(myloader);


    //... Rest of code remains same
}

function myexitftn(evt:Event):void
{
    myloader.unloadAndStop();
    removeChild(myloader);
    myloader = null;   

    removeChild(myhomeButton);
    gotoAndStop(1, "SomeOtherFrame");
}
```

Comment: Still the same problem. I had already thought of this and tried this before.